# What software can I use to read vlv & vli disk image file?

Tags: data-recovery, disk-image

It is a pretty old disk image created in 2008.

There are two files

- `ST38421A.part1.vlv` 5,198,984,607 bytes.
- `ST38421A.vli` 111 bytes

The first 8 bytes of the `.vlv` file is `VLDskImg`

The contents of `ST38421A.vli` is

```
[SIGNATURE]
SIGNATURE={985DED36-057F-4203-BAB2-61BCCEBB6D4F}
[FILESLIST]
COUNT=1
FILE1=ST38421A.part1.vlv
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I still haven't managed to find a software to open the file. I figured out the structure of the `vlv` file:

- First 512 bytes seems to contain header information such as disk model and size

It is followed by some "blocks" of data, each block contains:

- 256 x 4 = 1024 bytes of unsigned int array (little-endian). They are the ending offsets, relative to the beginning of this "block", of 256 "chunks"
- 256 "chunks" follows, each chunk is either DEFLATE compressed (when length < 131072 bytes, uncompressed size = 131072 bytes) or uncompressed (when length = 131072 bytes)